# Match optional string when random strings present between groups

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to python and I was having trouble with matching optional strings when can be any number of strings between the groups. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

I want the word following `'brown'` and if the word `'lazy'` is present I want the word following it as well, i.e:

```
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'      --> ('fox', 'dog')
'The quick brown fox'                              --> ('fox', '')
'The quick brown fox dfjdnjcnjdn vvvv lazy mouse'  --> ('fox', 'mouse')
'The quick brown fox lazy dog'                     --> ('fox', 'dog')
```

Here is what I tried, but it is not working

```
re.findall(r'brown (\S+)(.*?)(lazy )?(\S+)?', str)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you made a typo in your third example.  Your output has `'fox'` but your string has `cat'`.  I changed `cat'` to `fox` since that looks like what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, that was my intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to get the words you're looking for:

```
brown (\S+)(?:.*lazy (\S+))?
```

Which would give a list of tuples, with the empty string if `lazy` is not present.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
... The quick brown fox
... The quick brown fox dfjdnjcnjdn vvvv lazy mouse
... The quick brown fox lazy dog"""
>>> re.findall(r'brown (\S+)(?:.*lazy (\S+))?', s)
[('fox', 'dog'), ('fox', ''), ('fox', 'mouse'), ('fox', 'dog')]
>>>
```

`(?: ... )` is used to make groups that won't get captured, so what's inside won't necessarily get into the tuple/list with `re.findall` unless it is itself within capture group(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern such as:

```
(?:brown|lazy)\s(\S+)
```

Below is a breakdown of what it matches:

```
(?:brown|lazy)  # The words 'brown' or 'lazy'
\s              # A whitespace character
(\S+)           # One or more non-whitespace characters
```

And here is a demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:brown|lazy)\s(\S+)', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
['fox', 'dog']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:brown|lazy)\s(\S+)', 'The quick brown fox')
['fox']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:brown|lazy)\s(\S+)', 'The quick brown fox dfjdnjcnjdn vvvv lazy mouse')
['fox', 'mouse']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:brown|lazy)\s(\S+)', 'The quick brown fox lazy dog')
['fox', 'dog']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any way I can get the result as a tuple for all matches on a line

Comment: Simple call `tuple()` on the result:  `tuple(re.findall(r'(?:brown|lazy)\s(\S+)', 'The quick brown fox'))`.

Comment: No, then it is going to turn the entire thing to a tuple. What I meant to say was that the string being matched against could be multi-line and it would be nice if there was a way I could get each line as tuple, for this example it would be [('fox', 'dog'), ('fox', ''), ('fox', 'mouse'), ('fox', 'dog')]